# What is an efficient way to calculate Jacobian using symbolic variables in C++?

Tags: c++

I am looking for something similar to sympy in Python (http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/index.html)

Comment: For recommendations, try posting to SoftwareRecs@StackExchange.com.

Comment: If your code is working, and you would like an efficiency review, post the relevant, working, code to CodeReview@StackExchange.com

Comment: I am yet to code it. I am wondering how I should go about it. I only way out I could think of was to hard code the derivatives.